# What is the lowest number of blocks mined in a day?

Tags: hashpower, block-interval

There were only 67 blocks mined on the [2021-06-27 (UTC)](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/blocks?q=time(2021-06-28%2000:00:00..2021-06-27%2000:00:00)).

Is this the lowest number of blocks we have ever seen in a day? Or have we seen numbers counts in the past?

Answer (score 1):

It was lowest since 2011 according to chart shared in a tweet [thread](https://twitter.com/glassnode/status/1409464805874937862):

[image: glassnode-blocks-chart]

But it was not lowest overall because there were fewer blocks mined in 24h a few times in 2009.

[image: blocks-2009]